# How to know which qwidget in a ui form got the focus in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qwidget

I am new to PyQt. I designed a form in QtDeveloper which have three controls. One push button, one combo box and one line edit. The name of the line edit widget in my ui form is myLineEdit.  I want to know which Qwidget got focus (QLineEdit or QComboBox). I implement the code obtained from internet. When the code run, a separate line edit is created and it works fine. But I want to give the focusInEvent to myLineEdit widget created in the .ui form. My code is given. Please help.

```
class MyLineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyLineEdit, self).__init__(parent)
    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        print 'focus in event'
        self.clear()
        QLineEdit.focusInEvent(self, QFocusEvent(QEvent.FocusIn))

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.myLineEdit = MyLineEdit(self)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must implement the `eventFilter` method and enable this property to the widgets that are needed with:

```
{your widget}.installEventFilter(self)
```

The eventFilter method has as information the object and type of event.

**Example**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

uiFile = "widget.ui"  # Enter file here.

Ui_Widget, _ = uic.loadUiType(uiFile)


class Widget(QWidget, Ui_Widget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.lineEdit.installEventFilter(self)
        self.pushButton.installEventFilter(self)
        self.comboBox.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.FocusIn:
            if obj == self.lineEdit:
                print("lineedit")
            elif obj == self.pushButton:
                print("pushbutton")
            elif obj == self.comboBox:
                print("combobox")
        return super(Widget, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Ouput:

```
lineedit
pushbutton
combobox
pushbutton
lineedit
```